# Get url of webViewDidFinishLoad in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm loading a web page in a `UIWebView` and the web page contains a couple of iframes, for example an embedded youtube video.

I see all the separate requests for these iframes via `request.URL` in

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

But when they finish loading, I can't see what finished loading because there's no `NSURLRequest` object in

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
```

So what happens is:

1. shouldStartLoadWithRequest main.html --> YES
2. shouldStartLoadWithRequest iframe1.html --> YES
3. shouldStartLoadWithRequest iframe2.html --> YES
4. shouldStartLoadWithRequest iframe3.html --> YES
5. Something finished loading, but what?
6. Something finished loading, but what?
7. Something finished loading, but what?
8. Something finished loading, but what?

What I ultimately want to achieve is to just listen to the finish event of the main page and ignore all events triggered by iframes. How can this be achieved? Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Are `[webView URL]` (for `WKWebView`) and `[[webView request] URL]` what you're looking for in the delegate methods?

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon I think, seems that in WKWebView the finish event is only triggered for the main page. Questions remains for UIWebView though (edited my question accordingly). Thanks for the suggetsion @Larme webView.request.URL gives me the main page url every time even if its an iframe triggering the event.

Comment: Maybe with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218493/how-to-tell-the-difference-between-an-iframe-loading-vs-entire-page-loading-in ?